# Jquery, calendar: how to get the value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, calendar, jquery-events

I am using this calendar: http://javascriptcalendar.org/

to pick a specific day. It works fine. I want when the user selects a day from the calendar to display a message in a div which will also contain this day. However, even though I have tried the Javascript and jQuery events: `onclick`, `onchange`, `select`, `keyup` I can't make it work. These events work only if after picking the day I press with my keyboard a char.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from the plugin's website.

```
g_calendarObject.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
        var obj = g_calendarObject.getSelectedDay();

        alert("a date was just selected and the date is : " + obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year);
});
```

I'm sure you've probably already seen that though, maybe you can make a jsfiddle and I can probably help a little better then.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<input type="text" id="dt">
    <div id="showdate" style="display:none">
    </div>
    <script>
    $("#dt").change(function() {
    $("#showdate").css("display", "block");
    var txt=$(this).val();
    $('#showdate').text(txt);

    });
    </script>
```